# PHP register globals support in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php

I've been using PHP 5.2 and using register_globals ON. Now I'm moving to PHP 5.3 and I understand I have to change some of my coding. I've read up on this but I still don't have a clear picture of what changes I have to make.

In 5.2 I use

```
session_start();
```

at the top of my forms. In 5.3 do I still need to do this?

I also currently use vars like this

```
$_SESSION[php_g_name"] = "John";
```

or

```
if ($_SESSION["php_g_name"] == "")
```

Is that ok to continue to use in 5.3? If not, what's the syntax for vars?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: that's perfectly fine. but without register_globals, `$php_g_name = 'foo'` will not work. And shame on you for using register_globals in the first place. It is (and always has been) the single most insanely stupid design "feature" of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Register_Globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) was one of the most iconic but also one of the most reviled 'features' of PHP.  It was what allowed PHP in the early days to gain so much traction and usage.

you could do this

```
<?php
 //for a url example.com/myfile.php?UserName=Toby
 echo "Hello $UserName";
?>
```

It made it very easy to get access to variables from _GET and _POST but also (as in your case) _SESSION.

**However** it has enormously bad security implications and has been off by default since php 4 or so (someone will tell me exactly).

Basically what it means to you is that if you were doing this to get access to your session variables

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $php_g_name ;
```

with register globals $php_g_name would have had a value, now it wont.  This however will work.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION["php_g_name"] ;
```

If you are currently doing that anyway you should be fine.  You will need to change you code to always use the containing array eg `$_SESSION`

Comment: I'm using the echo $_SESSION[php_g_name"] method and not the echo $php_g_name method so it looks like I might be fine with my code to move to PHP 5.3+ right?

Comment: Should be fine, but maybe try on a test server first to see if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still need to set session start at top each file.
For variables, `$_SESSION["php_g_name"]` will work, however `$php_g_name` will not, unless you state that `$php_g_name = $_GET(or session)["php_g_name"]`